# how to increase speed of my application?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

My applications requirement is to contact the webservice, get the xml, parse it and display it using a listfield. I am calling all this classes xmlhandler, objectmodel, displaying it using a lisfield from a class that extends mainscreen which is making my application slow.

Can anyone suggest me how to make it fast?

Is it a apt to popup a loading screen and start a thread for contacting the webservice, get the xml, parsing it and kill the thread, then populate the listscreen and display it?

suggestions of any kind is welcome!

Comment: That's usually the right way to do it, I don't know if that's the way it is done in blackberry.

Comment: are you fetching the entire xml before starting to parse it? that will waste time. Are you using Buffering on the stream? that will help. More than that probably requires seeing what you have done.

Comment: You can put a loading message or animation overlay on the listbox.

Comment: @Hemal: which one are you mentioning? the pop a loadingscreen and start a thread?

Comment: Yes, network is going to take time. Parsing xml will take time too. So it is better to do it in a background thread.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy:I have to fetch the entire xml, that is how the webservice is designed, it is a news paper application

Comment: @Byron: sure, is it  efficient to use a seperate thread for xml fetching and parse it ?

Comment: @Hemal Pandya : is there any api in blackberry? or can I use java thread, sorry if I am sounding ignorant or something.. I am working on this for first time

Answer (score 1):

Test the speed of every part of your program. What I usually use is `System.nanoTime()` and find the difference in time after every part of the program.

Comment: System.nanoTime() is not available in J2ME.  Use System.currentTimeMillis() instead.

Comment: @simplyianm : :) sure, you have it!!

Answer (score 0):

Find out which part is slow before you do anything else.
Otherwise, you'll waste a lot of your time on the wrong parts.

For doing this kind of timing work, I often will do internal logging into a StringBuilder, or maybe just into an ArrayList holding raw, unformatted data.  After the test is over, I format and output the data.  This minimizes the effect of the logging on the timings.

Comment: thanks for your reply Ed staub, It is taking around ten sec to open the app..In most of the similar applications that timing is common, but my I am confused about using a seperate app for the fetching process without disturbing the mainscreen class..can you post some example for it?

Comment: @Newbie - I didn't mean to imply anything like that.  If I understand you right, the slowness is in opening (initializing) the app - right?  I meant to temporarily include this ultralight logging in the app.  When it's open, it would dump/display/write-to-disk the log (whichever's convenient).

Comment: it's java-me, vectors and stringbuffers, which both need to be synchronized so you wont get the same performance. You're better off with the BB system logger, or system out to the console.

Comment: @Ray - console - really?  My experience is that gets blocked a lot, sometimes becoming a dominant time-sink, because it blocks on I/O.  But I'm not a -me guy.  Do you think that the system logger doesn't synchronize?  Possible, but I'd be surprised.  Does it do I/O?  In that case, it may synchronize over I/O too, which will be far worse than any vector object sync.

Comment: The bb system logger runs as a separate application, I believe it's only logging to memory, granted it's probably using a synchronized vector anyway:) but I don't think there is any avoiding that.

Answer (score 0):

I can only gues so forgive me if I'm  wrong - to me it seems more efficient to create the item of list field only when they're really viewed. So I'd try to keep **in memory only the parsed strings and create only the UI items currently to be displayed**,  discard invisible. To make it more smooth you can you can extend it one or more pages before and after current page.

This way the number of displayed items is always constant. You may also add paging to the service layer to limit number of records trabsmitted at once.

Comment: thanks for your reply binary_runner, first page in my application is listfield, it is a news paper application..